# On the definition of independent and dependent random variables

Tags: statistics

In section 7.4 of "Understandable Statistics", the following definitions are given:

Two samples are independent if sample data drawn from one population are completely unrelated to the selection of sample data from the other population

Two samples are dependent if each data value in one sample can be paired with a corresponding data value in the other sample

In more adequate textbooks, I believe the definition for $X$ and $Y$ being independent random variables is that $P(x=X,y=Y)=P(x=X)p(y=Y)$ and that the two variables are said to be dependent otherwise.

I'm teaching an elementary statistics course out of the former textbook this coming fall semester and would appreciate a comment from somebody more knowledgeable in statistics about the definitions from "Understandable statistics". What are the shortcoming of these definitions? In what ways is it accurate?

Comment: For events $A$ and $B$, having $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ is the definition of independence.  If $X$ is a discrete random variable, then $X=x$ is an event, and similarly $Y=y$, so independence of $X$ and $Y$ requires $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ to be true for all values $x,y$.  It gets more complicated for continuous random variables, but you can say  independence of $X$ and $Y$ requires $P(X\in x,Y\in y)=P(X\in x)P(Y\in y)$ to be true for all sets of values $x,y$.

Comment: Don't much care for the second definition, even taking it as an informal guide and not a formal definition.   For instance, if two samples share a large block of individual members, but also contain smaller groups which are truly chosen independently...one would certainly say that these samples were dependent, but I don't see what "pairing" the authors have in mind.

Comment: For that matter, I'm not  a fan of the first definition either.  "completely unrelated" seems unreasonably strong.  They are, after all, drawn from the same population and the members of that population might have many, many things in common with each other.